# How to set default value within select tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

So basically, what I have is this.

My Script:

```
scope.exampleDetailsForm = {
    dropdownItems: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5"],
    itemSelected:  ''
};
```

My HTML:

```
<form name="example" role="form">
       <table id="exampleTable">
           <tr>
               <td class="tableCell">
                   <label for="LOB">Example:</label>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <select ng-model="example" 
                      ng-options="example as example for example in exampleDetailsForm.dropdownItems">
                   <select>
               </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Now, my `itemSelected` gets populated from my db dynamically further down in the script. So what I'm trying to do is:

If `itemSelected` is not null, I want the default option for my select to be the corresponding value in dropDownItems.

So if a user logs on and selects something with the `itemSelected` value of "Sample 4", then this is what I want displaying as the default option for my select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
scope.exampleDetailsForm = {
    dropdownItems: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5"],

}; 
scope.exampleDetailsForm.itemSelected =  scope.exampleDetailsForm.dropdownItems[0]
```

And changing the `ng-model="example"` for `exampleDetailsForm.itemSelected`

I asume you want to use that variable as the actual selected example.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ng-init="example=exampleDetailsForm.itemSelected"` to the `select` element

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form name="example" role="form">
   <table id="exampleTable">
       <tr>
           <td class="tableCell">
               <label for="LOB">Example:</label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <select ng-model="example"
                  ng-init="example=getSelectedItem()"
                  ng-options="example as example for example in exampleDetailsForm.dropdownItems">
               <select>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS

```
    $scope.exampleDetailsForm = {
        dropdownItems: ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5"],
        itemSelected:  ''
    };

    $scope.getSelectedItem = function(){
        if ($scope.exampleDetailsForm.itemSelected !== ''){
            var index = $scope.exampleDetailsForm.dropdownItems.indexOf($scope.exampleDetailsForm.itemSelected);
            return $scope.exampleDetailsForm.dropdownItems[index];
        }else{
            return $scope.exampleDetailsForm.dropdownItems[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you show me an implementation of this within the angular, please?

Comment: Updated. Keep in mind, this probably isn't the optimal solution as I'm still learning Angular, but this is how I might approach this problem.